# How to delete each third row from <tbody> using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete each third row in this code.
How I can do this?
Thanks for any answers

I was trying to do something like this:

```
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');

for (let i =0; i <table.rows.length; i++) {
  if (i%3 === 0 ) {
    table.deleteRow(i)
  }
}
```

I have this table:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>First row.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second row.</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>DELETE 3</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>4 row.</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>5 row.</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>DELETE 6</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>First row.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second row.</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>DELETE 9</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I need a script which I will put in the console of my browser and I will delete each third row in anything table. Thank you!

Comment: what's wrong with your javascript code?

Comment: using a class or an id to identify the trs to delete would be a better idea and would be easier to use with a css selector

Comment: @PanosK, using `:nth-child()` would do the job without the need to modify the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for (let i =0; i <table.length; i++) {
  if(i%3==2)
    table[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>First row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DELETE 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DELETE 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DELETE 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any reason you chose not to use `.forEach()` from the NodeList returned from `.querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, no such reason, I just wanted to stick with OP'S code......thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that as soon as you remove a row from your table, the tables **rows.length** property decreases by 1 as well as the the order of your rows changes. (thus after removing, the next third will be a different element as before removing)

Better iterate over the elements from the last to the first like:

```js
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var a = myTable.rows.length - 1; a > 0; a--) {
  if ((a + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    myTable.deleteRow(a)
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, really all work fine!
Thank you, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over a selection of all the rows.

```js
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#mytable tr")

Array.from(tableRows).forEach((row, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row); 
  }
})
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or use ECMAScript 2015's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do the same thing

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('#mytable tr')].forEach((el, i) => {if (i % 3 === 2) {el.remove()}});
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8 row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELETE 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```